# ComboBox connection with database

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox

I am trying to link the combobox with my database column "name", for this purpose i am watching a tutorial from youtube. Everything is going smooth but now I am having problem with connecting it with a combobox. I am new to VB.Net, so please guide me. 
Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    con = New SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\zeeshan\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Tutorials\Tutorials\Register.mdf"
    Dim READER As SqlDataReader


    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from dbo.edata"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(Query, con)
        READER = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While READER.Read
            Dim sName = READER.GetString("name")
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(sName)
        End While




        con.Close()

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

I have attached the error pic as well. This code is working fine in video tutorial but I m having problem using it.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use index column

```
While READER.Read
      Dim sName = READER.GetString(1)
      ComboBox1.Items.Add(sName)
End While
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 datatable dt= cmd.ExecuteReader

      if(dt.rows.count>0)
    {
            foreach(Datarow dr in dt.rows)
         {
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
         }
     }
```